# Can't seem to download the tiles for my map application

Tags: android, google-maps

this is my first question and I've been messing around with android for just a couple of days now.

The problem arose when I tried to follow an example code to experiment with the MapView class (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

I installed the Google APIs add-on in my SDK and did everything just as stated in the tutorial and the AVD ran the code perfectly, except for the fact that I got an empty grid instead of the actual map I thought I was supposed to see.

It looks like my debug key is wrong or something, but again here, I did everything just as stated in the tutorial. In fact, here's the line in my main.xml where the api key is specified:

```
    android:apiKey="48:C6:36:64:4A:DA:92:EF:D7:9E:BA:CD:26:45:EB:0D"
```

I got this key using the keytool command just like this:

```
    $ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /home/nelson/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

I tried the built in map application that comes with the AVD when you install the google API and it works perfectly, so there must be something wrong with my application, but I just have no idea of what. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Nelson R. Perez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android:apiKey="48:C6:36:64:4A:DA:92:EF:D7:9E:BA:CD:26:45:EB:0D"

That's not your API key. Thats the fingerprint of your signing key.

Follow the Maps API key instructions starting from [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#registering), and you should be OK.